# Getting all (but only) the windows processes which are shown by pressing alt+tab

Tags: c#, windows

I want to get all (but only) the windows processes which are shown by pressing alt+tab.

With `Process.GetProcesses()` I could get all processes and with

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
```

I could filter most of the processes which are not visible, but there are still some invisible processes like Settings or the Microsoft Store left, which I never opened. How can I also filter these processes?

Comment: ALT+TAB does not show processes, but windows. Get a list of visible windows.

Comment: `var windowed = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Id > 4 && p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero).ToArray();`. A few can have a Window handle but not a *visible* Window.

Comment: @Jimi what's the reason for `p.Id > 4` that in the where?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ To skip `System Idle` and `System`: those two guys don't like to share. I always add that condition.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the explanation, makes sense!

Comment: [Which windows appear in the Alt+Tab list?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071008-00/?p=24863)